# How to change the way opencart calculates price in the shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, opencart-3

Opencart calculates price in php with $price * quantity. How can I get open cart to calculate customfieldnumber * quantity instead? Or even a javascript variable that holds the total price.

I am doing a store, where the price needs to be square feet, but is charged by the box, so I added a custom js script to add the price per box under the square foot price. example:

wood floor: 
$1.00 /per sqft ( official opencart price  )
$10.00 /per box
box is 10 squarefeet

user inputs squarfootage: 100, javascript calculates this and adds boxes to qty
quantity = 10

total = $100

Now, if they add to cart, it will add $10, not $100 dollars, because opencart uses the price set in price field.

I need it to, when added to cart, add $100, ie: quantity times box number

I looked at system/cart/cart.php and found probably where this is calculated, but my php is very basic right now, so no clue how to make it calculate the way I need.

the line is 252:

'total'           => ($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity'],

I was hoping I could just use my javascript variable that gets the total cost to display on page, but I guess php cannot easily just use a js variable. It would look like this    totalPrice * $cart['quantity'], but no go I guess

Is there a way to do this in php?

$total_price = htmltag.value * $cart['quantity']

I would appreciate any help given

Comment: Hacking the PHP code is NOT the right way to go about this. OpenCart is an extensible platform that allows one to write plugins to adapt the inner workings to one's own needs. You could write it or hire someone to.  Here is one example from the OpenCart Marketplace: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=20261&filter_search=per%20square%20foot. (I am not affiliated with OpenCart or the product listed here).

Comment: Thank you for the answer..but I want to hack php or the .twig files, I do not need to hire someone or pay for an extension. I already created javascript to handle the squarefeet to amount of boxes needed conversion, so that extension will not even help me. I need to have the price calculated by a custom html tag instead of the php $price variable

Comment: You could conceivably pass your js price calculation to the cart method and override price to use it, but *that would be a very bad idea* since it would potentially allow anyone to set whatever price they want and then add it to cart.  That's one of many reasons that price is not calculated client side.  You'll need to learn php and calculate your price using options to get this done.

Comment: This probably does what you want but it's not OC3 compatible: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24247